# Where can I find Nilavanti Granth in Hindi/English Translation?

Tags: translation-request, bhaskararaya

Nilavanti Granth is one of the great work of Indian mathematician Bhaskaracharya. I want it with Sanskrit slokas and their Hindi or English translation. Where can I find it ?

---

<sup>**Note:** This book had mathematical equations or something similar which one could use to talk to animals trees and plants.</sup>

Comment: As far as I find that might be [Leelavati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C4%ABl%C4%81vat%C4%AB) (लीलावती), not Nilavati ; A work of Bhaskaracharya. Sanskrit text with Hindi translation is available at Internet Archive: [Leelavati 1894 With Hindi Tika Venkateshwar Press](https://archive.org/details/Leelavati1894WithHindiTikaVenkateshwarPress).

Comment: Can you post link to the sanskrit text if possible?

Comment: @Pandya I don't have any. Actually this scripture we have lost. There is someone claiming on [**YouTube**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCA00UJIQFU) that they have the real scripture.

Comment: @Pandya No I am not talking about Leelavati.

Comment: Btw, what is that text about? Can you add some information in question body?

Comment: @Pandya Yes Done! Not able to make the texts small, Can you please edit ?

Comment: No such text exists. Its Lilavati.I asked my mathematician friend and got confirmed.

Comment: Helloo,, how can i get an english PDF , pls help

Comment: @BaBithaVaSanth I haven't found it yet. Let's wait for somebody's answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is not by Bhaskaracharya. Neelvanti is a text using many languages. The scripts used are also different in different places. It is also said that there is only one copy and it is inscribed on some kind of metal.It is supposed to contain the languages of animals and birds among other things. It has appeared and disappeared at various times. It is said that Swami Vivekanand had read it. It is also said that once it is read the reader lives at the most for six months. I have heard all this from my Grandmother about 50 years ago. All this is hearsay but recently there has been a lot of news on YouTube.

Comment: Swami Vivekananda has read it? Did you find this in any of His biographies? I have never read about this!

Comment: Btw is this Granth real is their a Sanskrit manuscript of it?