# What is Nilavanti or Neelavanti granth? What is so special about it?

Tags: tantra

I recently read about Nilavanti { Neelavanti } book just a description of it. Says it was a rare book not printed just written on a metal plate that too lost these days.

It had recipes for alchemy, medicines for terminal diseases, and ways to interpret the language of birds, animals and other interesting stuff such as walking on water and air, gold harvesting,

But Nothing much was available just these descriptions.
Is it just rumor or really a book of tantra or magic?
Had Swami Vivekanada read this book?

Comment: There is already a question on this. See this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33391/where-can-i-find-nilavanti-granth-in-hindi-english-translation According to the answer given, Swami Vivekananda did read it but there is no reference given.

Comment: @Rickross it is about Lilavati not Neelavanti.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find Nilavanti Granth in Hindi/English Translation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33391/where-can-i-find-nilavanti-granth-in-hindi-english-translation)

Comment: No it's talking about the text called Nilavanti only. @WitVault You can check again.